# cx_Freeze error "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

First time trying to use cx_Freeze, I'm trying to build a little game I made in PyGame. However, I'm getting an error. Here is my `setup.py` :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable("main.py", base = None)]
options = { 
    'packages': ["idna", "numpy", "pygame"]
    }

setup(
    name = "TheMaze",
    options = {"build_exe": options},
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'My first game!',
    executables = executables
)
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    executables = executables
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 340, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 211, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 612, in Freeze
    self._FreezeExecutable(executable)
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 211, in _FreezeExecutable
    self._AddVersionResource(exe)
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 127, in _AddVersionResource
    stamp(fileName, versionInfo)
  File "P:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32verstamp.py", line 163, in stamp
    h = BeginUpdateResource(pathname, 0)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

I've tried several things based on examples I could find on the internet, but I couldn't manage to make ti works.